# Mass assignment, nested form and current user as author

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-attributes, fields-for

I have a couple of objects, foo, bar and user.

I have a form for creating a new foo object, which uses simple_fields_for and accepts_nested_attributes_for to create a new child bar object at the same time.

Now, I want to set the current_user as the author attribute for the new bar, but I can't figure out how best to do this. (still new to Rails.)

I have tried the following in my create method within the foo controller:

```
def create
    @foo = Foo.build(params[:foo])

    @foo.bars.find(:first).author = current_user
```

However when I run this I get an exception.

```
undefined method `author=' for nil:NilClass
```

Can anyone offer any advice on how best to go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You likely need to build the `Bar` object under `@foo`. ie

```
def new
  @foo = Foo.new
  @foo.bars.build
end

def create
   @foo = Foo.new(params[:foo])
   @foo.bars.first.author = current_user
   if @foo.save 
     redirect_to @foo
   else
     render action: "new"
   end
end
```

A good resource for nested forms: http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1?view=asciicast

Provided you set accepts_nested_attributes_for in your model and correctly used `fields_for` in your form, `params[:foo]` will contain an element called `bar_attributes` that will contain the data entered on the form about the bar object. Look through the railcast I linked to for more info.

Comment: Hi Ian, Thanks for the quick reply.

How would I pass the appropropriate attributes into the new bar object? give up on the nested attributes and pass them in myself rather than through the foo object?

Comment: You should build the bar object in the new method, I didn't specify that. I'll update my answer to give you a better idea.

Comment: That is fantastic thanks Ian. That is essentialy what I was doing, with one key difference, I was using find(:first) rather than .first to access the bar object to set the author.